# How can I remove Escaped string from Json?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to send request to server. unable get correct format JSON . please help to resolve this error.
[ "{"ProductGroupId":"994475","ProductId":"994408"}", "{"ProductGroupId":"994475","ProductId":"999737"}", "{"ProductGroupId":"994475","ProductId":"999915"}", "{"ProductGroupId":"994475","ProductId":"1194875"}" ]

```
self.productGroupList = json.response.result.packages[0].productGroups for index in 1..<self.productGroupList[3].products.count{
    self.productGroupIdList.append(self.productGroupList[3].products[index].productGroupID) self.productGroupIdList.append(self.productGroupList[3].products[index].id) let dictionary = ["ProductGroupId": self.productGroupList[3].products[index].productGroupID, "ProductId": self.productGroupList[3].products[index].id] as [String : Any] do {
        let jsonData:Data = try JSONSerialization.data( withJSONObject: dictionary, options: .fragmentsAllowed ) let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)! self.Linelist.append(jsonString)
    }

    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    self.noOfCycleValuesDropDown()
}
}
}
catch{
    print(error)
}
case .failure(let error): print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)") // Handle the error if needed
}
}
}
```

I am Expecting request like below format

```
[
  {
    "ProductGroupId": "994475",
    "ProductId": "994408"
  },
  {
    "ProductGroupId": "994475",
    "ProductId": "999737"
  },
  {
    "ProductGroupId": "994475",
    "ProductId": "999915"
  },
  {
    "ProductGroupId": "994475",
    "ProductId": "999951"
  },
  {
    "ProductGroupId": "994475",
    "ProductId": "1014043"
  },
  {
    "ProductGroupId": "994475",
    "ProductId": "1194891"
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to reformat the code ?

Comment: Where do you see escape characters? If you are printing your json to the debug console you will see escape characters around the quotation marks,  it those aren't actually in the string, it is just how the string is shown in the console. What error are you getting?

Comment: The formatting on that code is so bad it's almost impossible to follow. You need to break it into 1 statement per line and use conventional indentation.

Comment: Format your code, and to clarify, print `dictionary` and `String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)` to let us understand what's really your issue as it's unclear: what's your current output, and what are the intermediary values, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can get desired JSON Data using Encodables very easily
For example create a product structre

```
struct Product: Encodable {
    let groupId: String
    let productId: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case groupId = "ProductGroupId"
        case productId = "ProductId"
    }
}
```

Then try to add the values the way you were doing in loop, but for example

```
var products: [Product] = []
products.append(Product(groupId: "994475", productId: "994408"))
products.append(Product(groupId: "994475", productId: "994408"))
products.append(Product(groupId: "994475", productId: "994408"))
products.append(Product(groupId: "994475", productId: "994408"))
```

And to get data that you need from json use this

```
/// This is what you need to send to server, use do try to get unwrapped object
let productsData: Data? = try? JSONEncoder().encode(products)
```